# How to test the UI of an Eclipse Juno RCP

Tags: eclipse, testing, frameworks, eclipse-juno

We're developing an Eclipse-based RCP. Recently we've updated to Eclipse Juno and currently we focus on quality, which of course brought automated tests into focus, since the application is quite big and the testing effort delays releases.

We're already writing JUnit tests, but I'm more interested in UI tests. With older Eclipses this would not be a problem. There are plenty of good test frameworks around. Unfortunately with Juno everything changed due to the added ability to switch out the default SWT UI by Swing or JavaFX (at least this is what I've understood about the changes causing problems)

So most of the test tools don't work properly anymore. From past experiences it seems that:

- **SWTBot** seems to get not much love lately and is very unstable (can't find elements in certain versions)
- **Window Tester** seems quite good, but has a lot of problems identifying an element during the test run (especially with pop-ups such as content assist or tool tips)
- Apparently **Froglogics Squish** supports Juno, but since a license costs about 2,5k Euro I have to pass
- The same seems to be the case for **QF-Test** (too expensive).
- This leaves **Jubula** (or GUIDancer, which is the commercial Jubula), which we've tried in the past, but which had similar problems as Window Tester and SWTBot (unstable in terms of changes to the Eclipse platform and difficulties to detect some elements)

I need to know, which tool to focus on / trust in. Does anybody have experience with one of the tools or is even currently testing a Juno RCP (or Juno itself for that matter)? Or does anybody know how Eclipse tests their own platform (if they even do it atm)?

Searching for information related to "test", "Juno" and "UI/GUI" only brings up the commercial products.

For me it is important, to find a tool, where I can use the developed test cased even in future releases, which means: A framework project, which has some support of the community to be able to adapt quickly. Also it is important to also find stuff like tool-tips, overlays or content assists/suggestions) - similar to a Selenium compared to basic HTMLUnit.

At this point I don't even care too much about integration, reporting or compliance to standards..

Comment: Apparently the open-source market does not support highly customized Juno RCPs, so you need to use the proprietary tools.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest you too look at [Xored's Q7](http://www.xored.com/products/q7/), which is used for GUI testing of some of Eclipse projects including Eclipse DLTK, Eclipse LDT, Eclipse Tigerstripe and the tool is just perfect : it let you develop dozens of UI tests per day per engineer, and do not have stability and incorrect-recording problems. It's designed specially and only to test Eclipse-based apps and obviously the best in the niche.

However it costs money, which can be a blocker for you (like squish), but they have a free Community version, which is enough for most of use-cases. As well as those Xored guys just introduced pay-per-testexecution pricing model -- the tools will be free and you have to pay as you go only per tests executed monthly (less than 5000 is free). More about new model is here [eclipse-testing.com](http://www.eclipse-testing.com)

Comment: I've tried Q7 for a couple of hours now. The content-assist handling is a bit cumbersome. The behaviour is sometimes a bit different from manual execution. I couldn't find some good documentation on the ECL commands and my main visual editor could not be accessed properly. It didn't use the correct coordinates specified in the script and drag/drop operations couldn't be performed as well. When recording and replaying it worked, but on test execution it didn't really drag the object. This inconsistency makes it almost impossible to use.

Comment: Hi @peter, Thank you very much for the feedback. I was too optimistic spreading words about Juno support, which is just introduced, and far from ideal. But the team would be happy to work with you to remove all the inconsistencies, would you be interested to contact us and point to bugs in details (like sharing your AUT if possible, etc). Thank you very much, and Kind Regards,

Comment: Tried the latest version on a different machine and it worked well. Most of my problems were solved. There are some rough edges, but compared with other testing tools (such as Squish) this is easy to use as a test developer.

Answer (score 4):

You can find a comprehensive table of GUI-Testing tools in the Eclipse Wiki:
http://wiki.eclipse.org/Automated_Testing#UI_tests

One important decision you have to make is, if you want to use your mouse to record/create tests (Jubula, QFTest, ...), if you want to be able to hand-write test-code (SWTBot, ...), or if you want to be able to do both (WindowTester Pro, ...).

Eclipse Juno is rather new, and I would expect problems with all of the listed tools, however the migration should not take that long since most of these tools mainly focus on testing SWT-widgets and Juno still uses SWT. So far I have not heard from any RCP Application seriously using JavaFX other than for technical demos, but I would be curious to see them!

The problem I think, is rather that testing Eclipse is hard and GUI-testing is especially hard.
You might want to have a look at this study which finds and explains the major problems:
http://swerl.tudelft.nl/twiki/pub/Main/TechnicalReports/TUD-SERG-2011-010.pdf

If you believe this study, JUnit-testing is usually preferable to GUI-testing. Well, with Juno you have the big advantage that Unit-testing Eclipse now is easier than it ever was because the framework switched from inheritance and singletons to dependency injection, which makes it far more testable.

Comment: Thanks for sharing some knowledge. I will take a look at the study. My main problem with Junit testing only is, that the interface itself can be very complex, which doesn't allow us to collect some of the problems that may occur. I know that Juno is quite new and my hope is that the test frameworks will catch up. However, with all the recent news/blogs/etc going around unfortunately I'm rather skeptic about a quick improvement of the established frameworks. But at least knowing, that this is the universe I have to deal with is important.

Comment: It is true that there are a lot of problems on top of the technical ones. For example, I prefer WindowTester Pro because it lets you record tests and generates code from the recording. Afterwards you can conveniently refactor the generated code and run it as a JUnit test from within Eclipse. However, Google at the moment makes it hard to contribute to the project, and the move to a first-class Eclipse project seems slow which defers the necessary migration.